# changing small RatingBar Style using android resource is it possible?

Tags: android, styles

aim using `android:Theme.Light` for my app but its showing `Blue` small Stars if i switch to `Theme.Dark` the stars become Yellow and that's what i need

i wan to use `android:Theme.Light` as premier theme for my app i don't wanna change it , and i want change small stars from blue to  yellow stars from android resource Style i don't want to use Custom RatingBar how to do that?

this is my ratingbar View

```
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="1"
android:rating="2.5"
android:id="@+id/ratingsmall"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but I think the only solution is to create you own custom rating bar to set the style you want.
I searched a way also before to modify the default styles for the rating bar but I did not find a way. 
Finally I followed this tutorial and succeeded to create my own rating bar:

http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/